# Convergent Periodic Sequence

Tags: real-analysis

how do I show that every convergent periodic sequence of Real numbers is constant?I have the intuition that is true,but I don't know how to prove.thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: Let $\langle a_k:k\in\mathbb{N}\rangle$ be your sequence. Suppose that it has period $p$ and that $a_n\ne a_m$. What can you say about the subsequences $\langle a_{n+kp}:k\in\mathbb{N}\rangle$ and $\langle a_{m+kp}:k\in\mathbb{N}\rangle$?

Comment: they are constant, and have different limits, thus the sequence would have 2 accumulation points, a contradiction.Thanks.

Comment: @Jr.: Yep, you’ve got it.

Comment: Another one: If a monotone sequence has convergent subsequence,prove that the sequence itself is convergent.

Comment: @Jr.: Let $L$ be the limit of the convergent subsequence $\langle a_{n_k}:k\in\mathbb{N}\rangle$. Assume without loss of generality that the sequence is non-decreasing. Let $\epsilon>0$; there is an $m$ such that $a_{n_k}\in(L-\epsilon,L]$ whenever $k\ge m$. What can you say about $a_k$ when $k\ge n_m$? Use monotonicity.